# How can I play a soundfont from my Casio AP-470 keyboard?

Tags: midi, digital-piano

I was able to install and run LMMS with a pair of nice soundfonts. I would like to press the keys on my keyboard, and instead of obtaining the piano default sound and the sound from the laptop, I would like to re-route the software output to be able to play but with the soundfont output only.

At the moment, if I use the MIDI recorder and then play my recording, I can get the soundfont playing from the piano's speaker, but I would love to use the soundfont for live sound. My idea is to play Blinding Lights and other songs that need a lot of effects.

Here's a diagram of what I want to do:
[image]

Update: I selected channels 1 and 16 as it was suggested in the answers, but I still can only get the piano default sound or piano sound + sound from the laptop.
[image]

Comment: Set the Casio to LOCAL OFF mode, if possible.

Comment: I did that, but it only helps to play MIDIs without accidentally pressing keys. I've added a diagram of what I want to do.

Comment: Check that there is no soft-thru feedback of MIDI messages coming back from LMMS to the Casio. Or set the Casio to send on channel 1 but receive only on channel 16 or something.

Comment: Where is the screenshot from? Did you change the settings on the Casio? Disconnect all cables except power from the Casio. If it is LOCAL OFF and no MIDI or USB cables connected, then pressing keys on the Casio should not produce any sound. If it still produces piano sounds, then it is not in local off mode.

Comment: thanks! the screenshot is from LMMS, I've read the manual and it looks there is no way to put it in local mode off

Comment: so far, I'm able to turn the volume off in the piano and play from the laptop, but I want to send the laptop sound to the piano

Comment: Go to the Casio's MIDI settings, find the setting "Local control" and set it to Off.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Casio's MIDI settings, find a setting called **Local control** and set it to **Off**.

According to the online PDF manual such a setting should exist.

Comment: thanks, the documentation for this model isn't exactly precise on this topic https://web.casio.com/app/en/piano/manual/BONDSYgfvkehwg.html

Comment: It's also a question of just knowing this stuff... I've used MIDI for almost 35 years, so the right keywords to search for come automatically. I found this PDF https://support.casio.com/storage/en/manual/pdf/EN/008/Web_AP470-E-3A_EN.pdf

Comment: WOW !! you've played keyboards for more years than my age... I quite envy being there in the 80s playing synths :)

Comment: If you want to play 80s stuff, now is a fantastic time to do that, because you can get so much stuff for your computer as virtual instruments. :) Things that were impossibly expensive for beginners like me back then, you can have in your virtual studio, as plugins or sample sets. And all these articles, tutorials, manuals, how-tos are available so you get to know all the tricks! You can easily have samples from Linn Drum, 606, 808, 909 etc. DX-7 emulations and the original SysX ... virtual models of Junos, Oberheims, Prophet-5, etc. One of my favourite things to play is Yamaha CP-70 samples.